# Stronger than AM-GM and a conjecture

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $a_i>0$ be $n$ numbers such that $\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i\leq 1$ then we have:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i\geq n \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i \right)^{\large\left({n+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-n(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i)^{1/n}}\right)^{-1}}.$$

A possible way to generalize this is the following conjecture:

> Let $f(x)$ be a increasing and convex function and $a_i$ be $n$ real numbers such that  $f(a_i)>0$ with $\prod_{i=1}^{n}f(a_i)\leq 1$ then we have:
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(a_i)\geq n \left( \prod_{i=1}^{n}f(a_i) \right)^{\large \left(n+\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(a_i)-nf\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i/n\right)\right)^{-1}}.$$

Any hints would be appreciable to solve this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do these inequalities come from? Why do you think they are true? – And to which mathematical contest is the question related?

Comment: The first inequality is formulated as a *fact.* Could you provide a reference for those who (like me) are not familiar with that stronger version of the AM-GM inequality?

Comment: I have
tried to improve the readability of your question by enlarging the indices. It is possible
that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.  Please
proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會: It seems to be that your edit changed the expression in the second inequality. For example, it was $n+\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(a_i)-nf(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n})$ the exponent on the RHS.

Comment: @MartinR Nice catch!  Nonetheless, this shows the importance of [avoiding fractions in subscripts/superscripts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189).  The letters were so *small* that I mistakenly thought that they were the same.  There were [old and experienced Math.SE users](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129956/question-about-rudins-theorem-8-22-proof-stirlings-formula-part-b?noredirect=1#comment6448252_3129956) who *can't* read such small letters.

Answer (score 4):

For the first inequality, write $A=\tfrac1n \sum a_i$ and $G=\prod a_i^{1/n}.$ We need to prove $A^{1+A-G}\geq G.$
But $$A^{A-G}=(A^A)^{(A-G)/A}\geq e^{-(A-G)/A}\geq 1-(A-G)/A=G/A$$
where the middle inequality uses $A^A\geq e^{-e^{-1}}\geq e^{-1}.$

The generalization is false, if my calculations are correct. Take
\begin{align*}
n&=4\\
a_1&=\tfrac12\\
a_i&=1\qquad(2\leq i\leq 4)\\
f(x)&=\begin{cases}x/e^2& (x\leq 7/8)\\
7/8e^2 + 8(1/e-7/8e^2)(x-7/8)& (x\geq 7/8)
\end{cases}\\
f(a_1)&=1/2e^2\\
f(a_i)&=1/e\qquad(2\leq i\leq 4)\\
A&=\tfrac1n\sum f(a_i)\approx0.29283\\
G&=\prod f(a_i)^{1/n}=(1/2e)^{1/4}/e\approx0.24092\\
F&=f(\sum a_i/n)=f(7/8)=7/8e^2\approx 0.11842.
\end{align*}
Then $0.80718\approx A^{A-F}<G/A\approx 0.82274,$ but the desired inequality is equivalent to $A^{A-F}\geq G/A.$