# Question about Rudin's Theorem 8.22 proof (Stirling's formula) - part (b)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

During the proof of Theorem 8.22, the following function is defined:
\begin{equation}
\psi_x(s) = 
\begin{cases}
\exp\left[-s^2\cdot h\left(s \sqrt{2/x}\right)\right] ~~~~~~~~ (s>-\sqrt{x/2})\\
0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(s \le -\sqrt{x/2})
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
where $h$ is a function defined by:
\begin{equation}
h(u) = \frac{2}{u^2}\left[u - \log(1+u)\right]
\end{equation}

The following statements are made about this function:
[image: statements]

---

How can I prove (b)?

---

I just got the answer by myself:

For $s>0$, I think this follows from Rudin's theorem 7.13:
[image]
and the fact that, for $s>0$, $\psi_x(s)$ is strictly decreasing in $x$.

For $s<0$ , $\psi_x(s)$ is strictly increasing in $x$.  And you can apply an alternative version of theorem 7.13 that holds for increasing functions. The proof of this alternative version is similar to the original proof and just replace the definition of $g_n$ by $g_n = f - f_n$.

[image]

Comment: Try to estimate the difference $\psi_x(s)-e^{-s^2}$.

Comment: Please [*don't* post scanned pages from textbooks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155601/259305).  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not
view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會. Thanks for thinking about these people (I am one of them).